# Fanybox gallery stop autoplay on hover

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a solution to stop the `autoPlay` if the user first *clicks* the "next" button? Or to stop the `autoPlay` if user *hovers* the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `$.fancybox.play()` method to *toggle* the fancybox (auto) slideshow on mouse `hover` within the `afterShow` callback like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        autoPlay: true, // starts slideshow
        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-outer").on("mouseover", function () {
                $.fancybox.play(false); // stops slideshow
            });
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we are targeting the `.fancybox-outer` selector since you could be *hovering* the navigation arrows area(s), and that wouldn't stop the slideshow.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gk922kxp/)**

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v2.x