# How to close a Fancybox after gallery is fully played?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

On my page images open a fancybox (multiple sets of images), with autoplay set to true. I would like to stop the fancybox after ALL images are shown (number of images vary). I tried

```
afterShow: function () {
    $.fancybox.close(); 
}
```

This works but stops the fancybox right after the first image. So I would need something like afterShowGallery. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Please try with `onPlayEnd: function()` event handler. It will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try calling the `close()` from within the `onPlayEnd()` event handler. This event handler gets called after slideshow has stopped. So instead of putting `close` call in `afterShow` event handler; do it in `onPlayEnd()` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.imagen').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        parent.$.fancybox(
            [ {href:'img/1A.jpg'}, {href:'img/1B.jpg'}, {href:'img/1C.jpg'} ],
            {
             // API options here
                onPlayEnd: function () {
                    $.fancybox.close(); 
                } 
            }
        ); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but didn't succeed yet, I'm not very good in js... Maybe you can help me and show where to put your call: 
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.imagen').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      parent.$.fancybox([
       {href:'img/1A.jpg'},
       {href:'img/1B.jpg'},
       {href:'img/1C.jpg'}
      ]); // fancybox
     }); // click
    }); // ready
    </script>
Sorry, code block doesn't seem to work in a comment...

Comment: hello @Taco, Can you please try with above modified code.

Comment: Hi @vijayP, thanks for the adjusted code, this works perfect. I have one additional question though, I would like to pause the autoplay when a mouse is over the current image in the fancybox. I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427239/fanybox-gallery-stop-autoplay-on-hover but this quits the fancybox, and I just want to pause the autoplay...

Comment: hello @Taco. Could you please add another question for this? So that user who are in above situation will refer this answer in future. I can modify this answer itself but other OP will get confused with additional code. So just add another question and comment me the question link. Thanks.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for now.